# How does Monte Carlo Exploring Starts work?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, monte-carlo-methods

[image: Flowchart]

I'm having trouble understanding the 5th step in the flowchart.

For the 5th step, the '*update the Q function by taking the average of returns*' is confusing.

From what I understand, the Q function is basically the state-action pair values put in a table (the Q table). To update it means to make adjustments to the state-action pair value of the individual states and their respective actions (e.g state 1 action 1, state 3 action 1, state 3 action 2, so on and so forth).

I'm not sure what '*average of returns*' means though. Is it asking me to take the average of the returns after $x$ episodes?  From my understanding, returns is the sum of rewards in a full episode (So, AVG=sum of returns for x episodes/x).

And what do I do with that '*average*'?

I'm a little confused when they say '*update the Q function*' because the Q function consists of many parameters that must be updated (the individual state-action pair value), and I'm not sure which one they are referring to.

What is the point of calculating the average of returns? Since the state-action pair value for a particular state and particular action will always be the same (e.g if I always take action 3 in state 4, I will always get value=2 forever)

Comment: Where did you get that screenshot from? What book, slides, etc., is that from?

Comment: Hands-on reinforcement learning with python.( Packt publishing)    https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/hands-reinforcement-learning-python

Answer (score 1):

each episode you will calculate the return, you will then update the action value or $Q(s,a)$  as the average each episode. Using the blackjack example from open [AI gym](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/blackjack.py) and using a discount factor of 1, you get the following

episode 1 
[{'state': (22, 10, False), 'reward': -1, 'action': 1}, {'state': (17, 10, False), 'reward': 0, 'action': 1}, {'state': (12, 10, False), 'reward': 0.0, 'action': 1}]

$Q((22, 10, False),0)=-1$

$Q((17, 10, False),1)=-1$

$Q((12, 10, False),1)=-1$

episode 2 
[{'state': (21, 10, False), 'reward': 1, 'action': 0}, {'state': (17, 10, False), 'reward': 0, 'action': 1}, {'state': (12, 10, False), 'reward': 0.0, 'action': 1}]

$Q((21, 10, False),0)=1$

$Q((17, 10, False),1)=0$

$Q((12, 10, False),1)=0$

For $Q((17, 10, False),1)$ and $Q((12, 10, False),1)$ is the average return 
i.e -1 for the first episode and 1 for the second.

Comment: Welcome to SE:AI!

Answer (score 0):

$Q(s,a)$ denotes the $Q-value$ for the state-action pair. It means the expected returns if we start from state $s$, take action $a$, and act according to whatever policy we are currently following.

Suppose we are in state $s_0$, take action $a_0$. To compute the returns, we would need to follow our current policy from whatever state we land up after taking $a_0$, till the end of the episode, and sum up the rewards (or discounted rewards) that we get along the way.

*Why average of returns?*
Because we would want to do this multiple times for a state-action pair and compute the average of all such episodes.

*Why multiple times?*
Generally, the environments and the transition function would have some randomness and we don't get the same reward every time.

*Why would you want to compute this?*
The idea is simple. Since our goal is to maximize the average return, if we compute Q-values for all the possible actions starting from state $s_0$, then we can compare between the values and decide which action is going to be most beneficial to take from state $s_0$.

Since this is a tabular approach, when they say update the Q-function, they just mean to update the Q-values.

As an example, suppose we are in state $s_0$ and can take actions $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$. We first compute the Q-values for $(s_0, a_0), (s_0,a_1), (s_0, a_2)$ pairs, and then we would choose the action which has the maximum Q-value out of these three.